# Install SMTP server and send email from localhost to localhost

Tags: python, email, smtp, localhost, trac

I see lot of posts regarding this. But I don't get the right information to work on this.

I know that it is possible to send email from localhost to Gmail. But I want to send email from my localhost to my localhost. Is this possible ? If yes, how to achieve it ? How I will receive the email if I don't have a domain or an application to receive like gmail.com, yahoo.com ?

Now if I receive the email locally (from localhost to localhost), I want to check if I can reply back to the sender (again receiver : localhost and sender: localhost)

If it is feasible I like to try it in python.

Why I'm  in need of it ? I'm testing a plugin called [mail2trac](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/MailToTracPlugin) which I installed it in my local machine with [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/). Now this plugin will work in such a way that whoever replies to the email, the email content will be parsed and it is added to the ticket as reply, resolve, closed etc.

PS: I dont have much idea about it, so if my question is completely wrong, pls update me. And I'm working in Linux machine.